# how do you center and left align columns, at the same time, in bootstrap or regular html5?

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

remember the days of tables?  remember how easy it was to make things happen, even if it was junky code?  then when divs and css became the standard, there were just some things that were not so easy to implement.  case in point...

how do i do this in bootstrap?  if bootstrap does not have this built in, then how is it done with regular html5, while still keeping responsive feature?

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td valign="top"><table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td><p>a</p>
      <p>abcd</p>
      <p>ab</p>
      <p>abc</p></td>
    </tr>
  </table></td>
<td valign="top"><table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td><p>ab</p>
      <p>abc</p>
      <p>abcd</p>
      <p>a</p></td>
    </tr>
  </table></td>
<td valign="top"><table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td><p>abc</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>abc</p>
      <p>abcd</p></td>
    </tr>
  </table></td>
<td valign="top"><table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td><p>abcd</p>
      <p>ab</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>abc</p></td>
    </tr>
  </table></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

here is bootstrap2 columns (not bootstrap3), but as you know the content is left aligned in each column, and even if we could center the content of each column, that's not what i want.  i want the content to be centered in each column and each new line should be left aligned.  also as an extra thing, bootstrap creates a left-margin from the 2nd column to the last column.  to get exact centering, i would think that those left margins would need to go away.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span3">
  <p>a</p>
  <p>abcd</p>
  <p>ab</p>
  <p>abc</p>
</div>
<div class="span3">
  <p>ab</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abcd</p>
  <p>a</p>
</div>
<div class="span3">
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abcd</p>
</div>
<div class="span3">
  <p>abcd</p>
  <p>ab</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>abc</p>
</div>
</div>
```

here is fiddle of the above:

http://jsfiddle.net/C4926/3/

same jsfiddle, but with borders on the table:

http://jsfiddle.net/C4926/4

Comment: Can you maybe draw a picture of the desired output?

Comment: new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C4926/4/ - notice now the width of each inner box is as wide as the longest line, and each line in the inner boxes is left aligned, but the inner boxes are centered in the cells of the outer table?  that's the way the div version should work, and responsively if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, it looks like you have the following code inside of `bootstrap-combined.min.css` which is overriding the width that `span3` uses:

```
[class*="span"], .uneditable-input[class*="span"], .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    float: none;
    display: block;              /* Needs to be inline-block */
    width: 100%;                 /* Overrides width you need */
    margin-left: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I believe that this will fix your problem:

```
.row-fluid .span3 {
    width: 23%;             /* Correct width for span3 */
    display: inline-block;  /* Allows columns to be inline */
}
```

To get your text aligned center-left, you can add the following css:

```
.row-fluid div[class*="span"] p {
    width: 25%;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C4926/30/)

EDIT/Alternative Solution - Get the regular (non-combined) version of bootstrap

Using the original version of bootstrap, [found here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) you can avoid the span classes and use `col-xx-xx` and then align the text within it using `text-center` and `text-left`. [New JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FR5Xk/)

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
        <div class="inline text-left">
          <p>a</p>
          <p>abcd</p>
          <p>ab</p>
          <p>abc</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
        <div class="inline text-left">
          <p>ab</p>
          <p>abc</p>
          <p>abcd</p>
          <p>a</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
        <div class="inline text-left">
          <p>abc</p>
          <p>a</p>
          <p>abc</p>
          <p>abcd</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
        <div class="inline text-left">
          <p>abcd</p>
          <p>ab</p>
          <p>a</p>
          <p>abc</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

One small CSS addition for aligning the text:

```
.inline {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: interesting solution, but i'm starting to think this scenario is impossible for html/css, html5/css3.  you still have to hard code a width for the inner content.  with the table method, the inner tables are as wide as the longest line.

Comment: plus it's not centered perfectly because 23% is not 25% and some of the columns are still using left margin, and it doesn't work responsively anymore, it's just fluid.

Comment: @leoarce I have added an alternative solution. I'm not sure if it is possible for you to get the standard bootstrap or not, but it makes things easier for your scenario.

Comment: not sure what you mean by original bootstrap, but that is bootstrap 3 (which came after bootstrap 2 so it's not original), which is completely different than bootstrap 2.  for BS3 it's a good solution.  i guess BS2 needs hacks.  thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was thinking that you were using a modified version of Bootstrap 3. I never used version 2, so I was not aware that it was the version you had. With 3, as you can see, it is much simpler to align columns/rows without a table. I hope that I helped!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
.span3 p {
    margin-left: -10px;
    padding-left: 50%;
}
```

Where you replace the -10px of the margin left programmatically with javascript to always be in the half of the widest `<p>` element width within that span3.

I admit that this is not the prettiest solution, but sort of gets done what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: how is the -10px changed programmatically with javascript to always be in the half of the widest <p> element width within that span3?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/C4926/42/ however this does not take care of refreshing and needs some polishing.